# Change icon of generated exe

Tags: .net, vb.net, icons, csharpcodeprovider

I'm generating an executable file with VB.NET using CodeDomProvider.

Is there a way to change the icon before the compiler creates the exe file?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the icon of the generated exe by specifying it in the [CompilerParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebe1ezfz.aspx) that 
you pass to the code provider, using the [CompilerOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.compileroptions.aspx) property.

```
Dim parameters As New CompilerParameters()
parameters.CompilerOptions = "/win32icon:C:\full\path\to\icon.ico"
```

You then pass these parameters to the [CompileAssemblyFromSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromsource.aspx) method. The generated exe will then use the specified icon as its application icon.

Comment: thanks man, i will try now to see if it works

LE: it works perfect, thanks a lot man

Comment: When i do this, and compile the code, i get an error: Source file 'Deployment' could not be found. If i remove this option and only keep /optimize, it compiles without issues. Is there something i'm not doing correctly?

Comment: Actually never mind... apparently for compiler options you must use short path names (8.3 format) for paths.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the project properties and select the icon from there.
Simple as that.

Comment: man, i have an VB 2008 application with a textbox. There i wrote some VB code and when i press GENERATE, the application use codeDom Compiler and generates an exe with that code from the textbox.

The file is an exe with an exe icon, and i want to change it somehow.

it's not just a Icon property of an form or application

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RessourcesHacker](http://www.01net.com/telecharger/windows/Utilitaire/manipulation_de_fichier/fiches/12390.html) AFTER the generation. Not the easiest way, but it works great