# Dynamically change application icon at compile time? (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, compilation, icons

I have two applications that I'm creating off of one codebase, resulting in two executables.  Is there any way to dynamically change the executable's icon depending on a compilation flag (or something of that nature)?

I'm using VS2010 and code is C# if that matters.

Comment: You might find a solution using compiler flags here ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125034/how-to-assign-a-custom-icon-for-an-application-which-is-compiled-from-source-fil

Comment: The /win32res option qualifies.  Creating the .res file is a bit unfun.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found is replacing the icon in the batch file I use for compilation

```
copy \Resources\%VENDOR%.ico \icon.ico
```